# Slow MySQL sessions table

Tags: mysql, performance

I am currently trying to figure out why the site I am working on (Laravel 4.2 framework) is really slow at times, and I think it has to do with my database setup. I am not a pro at all so I would assume that where the problem is

My `sessions` table has roughly 2.2 million records in it, when I run `show processlist` all the queries that take the longest relate to that table.

Here is an example screen shot:

[image]

Table structure:

[image]

Surely I am doing something wrong or it's not indexed properly?
I'm not sure as I'm not fantastic with databases.

Comment: Show us the entire `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: and SELECT (longest) and DELETE (second, which could be really blocker for all UPDATES)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin of the slowness was the fact that I was using database for sessions. Changed it to Redis and it's 100% faster now

Answer (score 0):

1. use explain on your query (it will provide output on your execution)
2. add index on your table